# Removing Android (app or lib) module from Android Studio project requires syncing project with gradle files at every project startup

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

Following the guides here on stack overflow I was able to create a pure Java program using Android studio.

Here’s what I did:

1. I created a new project with no activity
2. I added a java library module and created a main method inside the
   added java library class
3. Through “edit configuration” I configured Android Studio to start
   the class inside the Java library

Since I wanted to create a pure Java program I removed the app module from the project structure and deleted the app folder as well.

The problem is that, after removing the app module, every time I start the project I need to sync project with gradle files to show the java library folder.

If I do not sync project with gradle files the java library folder is hidden and all other folders and files in the project are highlighted with a yellow color.

Can you tell me if it it is possible to avoid manual syncing project with gradle files at every project startup?

Comment: Not only is syncing required every time you reopen this project, the build tasks are incomplete, as well. For example, without an android module present trying to run Java unit tests will not build the unit tests before trying to run them.

Comment: Android Studio bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122669484

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, this problem is the same as this defect I raised with Google: [Task graph, syncing is incomplete for Java modules when running unit tests from UI gesture if there is no Android module](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122669484)

This problem doesn't just cause this syncing issue. It also messes with the task graph such that Java unit tests will not be rebuilt prior to running them, leading to strange errors about missing classes *or* old test classes being run for days or weeks.

<strike>I have found no workaround, other than committing a dummy Android library module parallel to the pure Java modules.</strike> The problem with having to force a manual sync should be fixed in Android Studio 3.3.

Also, with 3.3 the task graph seems to be fixed, but invoking Run 'All Tests' on a clean build will still fail the first time. It is making the classes, though, so if you invoke that gesture immediately it seems to work. This may be a different defect.

Comment: I can confirm that the problem is fixed in Android Studio 3.3.